# Return value from batch file to powershell

Tags: windows, powershell, batch-file, return-value

I have a batch file which calls a SQL script to send an email. This batch file is embedded in a powershell. How do I return a success or a failure return code from the batch file to the powershell. I have tried the following

In Batch file

```
exit /b %ERRORLEVEL%
```

In powershell

```
cmd.exe /c 'C:\scripts\send_email_sp_prd.bat F'
if($LastExitCode -eq -0){
write-host "Success"
}
else
{
write-host "Failure"
}
```

Even if the SQL script fails, the batch files is returning a value of `0` which is not what I want. Is there a better/correct way to do this?

Comment: Stop embedding batch files in your powershell and just do everything in powershell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally, I would eliminate the batch file and do this all through PowerShell, this will be much easier in terms of manipulating or validating against command output. In the installer for SQL Management Studio on the feature selection install "Management Tools" to obtain the PowerShell module. Once the module in installed you could create a script to execute your job. Here is something I created quickly but you could probably use this or something similar:

```
Function Invoke-Sqljob {

[CmdletBinding()]
param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    [String[]] $ServerInstance,

    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    [String[]] $DatabaseName,

    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    [String[]] $Query
     )

Import-Module SQLPS

Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance "$ServerInstance" -Database "$DatabaseName" -Query "$Query"

}
```

You would execute Invoke-Sqljob as follows:

```
Invoke-Sqljob -ServerInstance "DB_Server\SQL_Instance" -Database "DB_Name_Here" -Query "EXEC send_mail_sp_prd"
```

If you are unable to or would rather use sql authentication you could utilize the -Username and -Password parameters of the Invoke-Sqlcmd cmdlet.

Hope this helps solve you problem.

Comment: Thanks Tyler and sorry for the delayed response. This was part of code written by someone else and I didn't want to change it way too much but in the end, I did change everything to Powershell from batch.

Comment: Not a problem Vibhav MS, glad you were able to get everything converted and working in PowerShell!

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if your post is the script, verbatim, but you have a - before the 0. Try changing the first line of the *if* block to *$LastExitCode -eq 0*

```
if($LastExitCode -eq 0){
   write-host "Success"
}
else
{
   write-host "Failure"
}
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing out but that was type when I keyed it in here.